# How to change counters in multiple docs in firebase efficiently?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently learning firebase & I wanted to create an e-commerce website.

I have a collection "products" and it contains products with fields name, price & quantity.
What I want is when a user creates an order of certain products with certain quantity. I want the quantity ordered to decrement from each of the product's quantity.

What I did is I created a cloud function which basically runs a transaction & in it, it fetches each item with its id from the fire store then checks if each item's quantity is greater than or equal to the quantity ordered by user, then I use FieldValue.decrement(qty) to decrement the quantity for each item.

However, this approach seems very resource heavy, slow & also has a lot of reads. I wanted to know if there is any better way to achieve this. Pardon me if I made some mistake while asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach sounds quite normal: if you want to check whether enough volume of a certain product is available before submitting the cart, you will have to read that product document.

The only alternative would be to **assume** that enough volume is available in your client-side code, and then let your server-side security rules perform the actual check upon write. For an example of this, see the documentation on [validating data in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation#use_existing_data_in).

With this approach, the client would simply send the `increment`/`decrement` instructions as a batched write, and would then handle the rejection by the server as a signal that there may not be enough stock of one or more of the products.

In the worst case (when there's not enough stock) you will still need to read all the products too to determine which ones are out of stock. But in the common case, this approach avoids having to read all products ahead of time.